# Chemical potential of an ideal quantum gas

Tags: statistical-mechanics, chemical-potential

As far as I understand from textbooks, absolute values of the chemical potential are meaningless, only changes have physical meaning. That would mean that, from statistical mechanics, one should only be able to determine $\mu$ up to a constant. However, it appears that [Kittel](https://jontallen.ece.illinois.edu/Public/BOOKS/Kittel-ThermalPhysics.80.pdf), eq. 12(a) page 121 obtains an absolute value for the chemical potential of an ideal gas:

$$ \mu = k_B T \log(n/n_Q)$$

where $n$ is the gas concentration and $n_Q=(m k_B T/2\pi\hbar^2)^{3/2}$. It seems that there are no undetermined constants in this expression. How is that possible then that only differences matter?

I think I understand that in terms of work only chemical potential differences are relevant, in that case the question is why doesn't a constant appear in the above expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In macroscopic thermodynamics, the value of internal energy $U$, or entropy $S$ or other derived quantities (the Gibbs energy $G$, the free energy $F$) is often thought of as depending on the arbitrary choice of the reference state where that particular quantity has some prescribed value, such as zero. Which state is chosen to be such reference state does not matter. This arbitrariness poses no real problem as all experimentally relevant results of the macroscopic theory can be formulated in terms of changes $\Delta U,\Delta S, \Delta F$, etc.

Chemical potential $\mu$ for a simple system obeys the relation
$$
dU = TdS -pdV+\mu dN,
$$
thus we can use as its definition
$$
\mu =\frac{\partial U(S,V,N)}{\partial N}.
$$
Since

$$
dF = -SdT -pdV+\mu dN,
$$
it also obeys the relation
$$
\mu =\frac{\partial F(T,V,N)}{\partial N}.
$$
It is an intensive quantity like absolute temperature $T$ and pressure $p$, and just like with those, the reference state where its value is zero is arbitrary, because values of $U$ and $F$ are arbitrary; and this arbitrariness is also in dependence on $N$, so it allows for different values of $\mu$.

However, by convention $T$ is absolute temperature, so no longer arbitrary, $p$ is absolute pressure, so no longer arbitrary. With $\mu$ it is less clear, since it depends on how we define energy $U$ and entropy $S$ (and these are additional conventions). If we change definition of  $U$  to $U+U_0$ (say, we want to take into account rest energy $mc^2$) $\mu$ will have different value than if we do not; similarly with $S$.

In quantum statistical physics which Kittel teaches in his book, we analyze some model of the thermodynamic system, and it is usual to adopt a specific definition of energy based on eigenvalues of a specific Hamiltonian operator and of entropy in terms of some definite number of quantum states, or in terms of partition sum over all quantum states. This leads to definite energy and entropy values for any microstate. In case of energy, the macrostate which implies quantum states with the smallest possible eigenvalues of the standard Hamiltonian $\sum_k \frac{p_k^2}{2m} +V$ (where $V$ is the standard pair-wise potential energy function, with no rest energy terms) is used as the one with zero or the smallest possible value of internal energy; and in case of entropy, the macrostate which has zero or the smallest possible number of allowed microstates (in simple cases, the ground state) is used as the reference state with zero or the lowest entropy. Thus the quantum models and calculations adopt specific definitions of energy and entropy, which remove this arbitrariness from the resulting thermodynamic quantities. But this is because we've chosen definite definition of energy out of infinity of the possible ones (the number of equivalent Hamiltonians is infinite, all differing by a constant shift), and we've chosen a specific definition of entropy, such as (microcanonical definition) entropy being log of number of states with energy lower than $U$, or (canonical definition) entropy being a specific derivative of the partition function, even though there is no real need to adopt such definition, except history and convenience.

This is mostly done for convenience, to simplify the formulae, verbal descriptions and the whole exposition. There is no real necessity to prefer one Hamiltonian to base definition of energy on and there is no real necessity to select one specific definition of entropy. It is possible to formulate the quantum statistics allowing for the arbitrariness in definition of energy and entropy and then it becomes clear the values of these thermodynamic quantities are arbitrary, depending on our conventions.

Comment: The only caveat in your answers is that it is typical to define the entropy in an absolute manner using the third law such that there is a universal reference entropy for a substance at 0 K. While it this arbitrary, it is as good as we are going to get for a universal value.

Comment: @MattHanson Third law does not say entropy has to be zero, only that it approaches constant value. Only a definition fixes it to zero, and this is arbitrary.

Comment: I didn’t say it had to be 0. But it will be a uniquely defined constant (usually 0) for any particular substance that is not arbitrary.

Comment: Yes, but that is still a definition, not a law. There is no law implying what value our definition of entropy has to assign at 0K.

Comment: @JánLalinský thank you. What confuses me is that pressure, magnetic field, and other quantities that may appear in the work term in dF or dU can be defined outside thermodynamics, without using thermodynamic potential derivatives. I guess I could define the chemical potential as the work required to move one particle from a reference state to the system, but what does my canonical partition function know about that reference state? Shifting the zero energy level has no effect on any measurable quantity because it cancels out in the canonical PDF, but it remains there in the definition of $\mu$

Comment: @Botond Some definitions are possible with no reference to entropy or free energy. Other seemingly mechanical quantities are connected to entropy or free energy, for example, surface tension, although related to measurable force, is a function of temperature, and is derivative of the free energy of the surface wrt surface area. You can define $\mu$ as work, but this has to be at constant volume and entropy, which is not trivial; as the system adopts the particle, it will have to change (we expect decrease) its temperature to keep the entropy constant.

Comment: @Botond Canonical partition function depends on the choice of the Hamiltonian, via a pre-factor $e^{-\beta A}$ with arbitrary $A$. This means also definition of free energy and internal energy depends on $A$. If $A$ is restricted to not depend on $N$, chemical potential does not depend on $A$ either, but there is no law requiring this condition. $A$ in the Hamiltonian can be proportional to $N$ and then chemical potential will depend on the constant of proportionality.

Comment: @JánLalinský, isn't it that $\mu$ is work, but constant S and V is required for it to be the internal energy change with $N$? At constant T, V the free energy change is $\mu dN$ which is actually work. Regarding the $A$ constant, if $A$ is proportional to $N$, doesn't it just set the zero level of the potential energy?

Comment: Work is originally a dot product of a force and displacement vector of the mass that is acted upon by that force; perhaps not the best word for change of internal energy associated with adoption of additional particle, because there need not be any mechanical work involved in this, just moving the boundary of the system is enough. The real problem however is that one has to be able to measure or define this change of energy associated with adopting the particle into the system. I don't know of a way except via the definition, $\mu = \frac{\partial U}{\partial N}\bigg|_{S,V}$.

Comment: @JánLalinský If one puts a potential step (eg. electric or gravitational) between the reference state and the system, isn't that the work of transferring one particle from reference to the system?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "putting a potential step ... between the reference state and the system". The particle can become part of the system by going from a place of low potential energy out of the system to the place of high potential energy inside the system, but this need not be associated with work of external force (just decrease of kinetic energy of the particle may be enough, or mental change of the imaginary system boundary may be enough). Change of internal energy via exchange of particles may be associated with work of external force, but it need not be.

Comment: @JánLalinský, are you aware of any paper/notes where thermodynamics (and specifically the thermodynamic potentials) is formulated and worked out so that all the "constants" related to the reference state are explicitly there?

Comment: I guess the weird thing is that, for instance, in $dF=-S dT +...$ there is the actual $S$ value in the change of $F$. So if $S$ is to be understood w.r.t. a reference state, then even the change $dF$ is w.r.t. that reference state. The fact that this reference state is there even in the change, not just the potential value bothers me deeply.

Comment: Nothing comes to mind, except maybe the derivation of the Sackur-Tetrode equation, where the authors did take care when evaluating the adopted definition of entropy so that the resulting entropy expression has some funny constants; I think these details in the entropy function have a dubious relevance to thermodynamics. As always those constants are artifacts of the specific definition adopted (e.g. phase volume/number of quantum states below an energy surface, instead of phase volume/number of quantum states of layer of thickness $\Delta E$ in the phase space/energy spectrum).

Comment: You're right that choices made when defining $S$ influence $F$, and also $U$ and other quantities. It is not for nothing that some people call these quantities "thermodynamic potentials" - they behave mathematically like potential energy does in mechanics/EM theory - they have certain arbitrariness of definition to them, e.g. in that adding or removing a quantity that remains constant during normal processes produces equally good "thermodynamic potential" obeying the same equations.

Comment: In case we demand entropy of simple single phase system is 
 to be an homogeneous function of first degree of $U,V,N$, then we have $U=TS-pV+\mu N$, and also $dU = TdS -pdV + \mu dN$, thus also necessarily $SdT - Vdp + Nd\mu = 0$. From the last equation we can see that if entropy definition is changed by adding some constant, or even function of $U,V,N$, while maintaining the property that the resulting entropy is homogeneous function of first degree, then necessarily such change of value of entropy (due to change of definition) implies also change of value of $\mu$.

Comment: For free energy we have $dF = d(\mu N - PV)$, thus  when state of the system changes, $dF$ depends on how the value of $\mu$ changes, and that depends on how $S$ is defined.

Comment: @JánLalinský thank you for the extended explanation. I agree with all of that. In the end it is precisely the name thermodynamic potential that I find weird. Mechanical or electric potential *values* are ambiguous but *changes* are well defined. A change in gravitational potential energy does not depend on the choice of the zero point. A change in electrostatic energy does not depend on the choice of the zero point of the electrostatic potential. Yet, the *change* in the free energy $F$ does depend on the zero point of the entropy and chemical potential.

Comment: I suspect chemists who carry out thermodynamic measurements are naturally more aware of this than physicists who typically approach the thermodynamic potentials via their relation to partition functions.

Comment: Yes that is an interesting difference. In mechanics, in the differential expression for work of external forces on a particle $dE = F_xdx+F_ydy+F_zdz$, all the terms are of the same kind, with both $F_x$ and $dx$ regarded as unambiguous (we do not consider different possible definitions of coordinates or forces, although we could), thus there is no room for changing some definition to change the value of $dE$. But in thermodynamics, we have $dU = TdS-pdV+\mu N$, where the coordinate $S$ is traditionally different, we regard its value as arbitrary and this makes also $dF$ is arbitrary.

Comment: If we select a single specific definition of entropy as the "main" one, which is usually done in quantum statistical physics, then all arbitrariness in these quantities goes away.

Comment: This is perhaps not so surprising when realizing most  quantities are a result of some definition, whether stated or tacitly assumed, and there are other cases where the arbitrariness shows up in differentials as well. For example, EM energy density and flux density cannot be proven to be the ones given by the Poynting formula, there is infinity of possible definitions differing by largely an arbitrary field, obeying the equation of continuity; thus differential of EM energy density at any single point of space is not fixed either.

Comment: Perhaps even more similar situation is in theoretical mechanics: let's take single charged particle in external EM field. Canonical momentum $\mathbf p$ and also its differential $d\mathbf p$ has arbitrary value due to arbitrariness in the vector potential $\mathbf A$. Thus even if $dH$ is not arbitrary, $dL = d(\mathbf p \cdot \dot{\mathbf r} - H)$ is, due to arbitrary $\mathbf p$ in the expression. Thus here, vector potential and canonical momentum are arbitrary just like entropy $S$ is, and change of $L$ is arbitrary just like change of free energy $F$.

Comment: @JánLalinský thank you very much.

Comment: @JánLalinský, adding extensive constants to entropy and internal energy leads to a shift in the chemical potential as shown here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/782269/empirical-equivalence-of-shifted-chemical-potential-mu-i
Such shift would modify the law of mass action (  https://sassafras13.github.io/LawMassAction/ ) because then $\sum \mu_i \nu_i = a + b T$ with $a, b$ constants. I suspect this is not relevant because one can just redefine their standard state, but I find it pretty wild that everyone writes  $\sum \mu_i \nu_i =0$.

Comment: @Botond I've left a comment under that question.

Comment: @JánLalinský, great points, thank you.